# sapui5 sap.m.popover won't open my control

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I have a button:

```
var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
                    text: "Press me",
                    press: function (oEvent) {
                        if (! this._oPopover) {
                            this._oPopover = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.my.library.Popover", this);
                            this._oPopover.setModel(true);
                        }
                        var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
                        var oMyControl= this._oPopover.getAggregation('content')[0];
                        oMyControl.setPlaceholder("Hello World");
                        jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function () {
                            this._oPopover.openBy(oButton);
                        });
                    }
                })
```

And i have my xml Fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:d="sap.my.library">
    <Popover>
        <d:myControl value=""/>
        <!--<Input></Input>-->
    </Popover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Now, when I click the button, nothing happens, only if I click it many times, my control appears.
I can say that for every 10 quick buttons clicks, my control appears maybe once.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this._oPopover has a value. Can you console log something within the if (! this_oPopover) fork?

Answer (score 2):

this._oPopover is defined within an anonymous function declared within the button declaration.

IT CANNOT refer to a view field as you probably expect it to.

My suggestion :

```
var onButtonPress = function (oEvent) {
     if (! this._oPopover) {
         this._oPopover = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.my.library.Popover", this);
         this._oPopover.setModel(true);
     }
     var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
     var oMyControl= this._oPopover.getAggregation('content')[0];
     oMyControl.setPlaceholder("Hello World");
     jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function () {
         this._oPopover.openBy(oButton);
     });
}

var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Press me",
    press: this.onButtonPressed.bind(this)
});
```

[code not tested!]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that 'this' is not referring to what you expect because your object is created within an anonymous function?  See [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/) explanation (ahem)

I believe the preferred pattern is to have the button press call a function in the main view where 'this' refers to the view scope.

I have a working example as follows: in then main view I have a button...

```
<Button
    press="showDialogue"
/>
```

and the code of the view controller...

```
    showDialogue: function(){
        if(!this._oConfirmDialog){
            this._oConfirmDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sapui5.muSample.view.ConfirmDialog", this);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._oConfirmDialog);
        }
        this._oConfirmDialog.open();
    },
```

Note the use of **view.addDependent()** which lets the dialogue fragment access the view model AND destroys the dialogue instance in line the main view lifecycle events (according to the docs).

Or...you could create a local variable to capture the 'this' you actually want to refer to...

```
var contextThis = this;
```

just before your line starting

```
var oButton = ...
```

then change references to `this` inside the anon function to `contextThis` if you can't change the pattern.

Comment: Waiting for the flamers to comment having raised discussion of holy grail 'this' subject...